# Is it important to use Asp.Net Core SignalR with React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to create a Social Network With Asp.net Core, React & Redux. But I don't know should I use SignalR with Redux or not? As a Middleware I want to use Redux-Thunk and it's fast.
But still the question is should I use SignalR with Redux?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend upon the environment and the requirement for a long term.
SignalR would give you the capabilities for asynchronous requests,but that you can achieve through thunk or saga.
My recommendation would be to you start designing your API first and a mock UI to render your page ,and then check whether redux-thunk would solve your problem or not.